# Open a Mac application using Coffescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, atom-editor

I'm writing a package for the Atom text editor from Git and it uses Coffeescript. I have a keybinding that will initiate the function I am creating.

What do I need to write to simply open an application? In this case, I want to open the Transmit.app.

Comment: Would this be as part of your init script or in a package?

Answer (score 2):

Running a process is pretty simple with `spawn` from node or the built in [`BufferedProcess`](https://atom.io/docs/api/v0.73.0/api/classes/BufferedProcess.html) from Atom. `BufferedProcess` wraps spawn and provides standard output and error line buffering.

Example from [the docs](https://atom.io/docs/api/v0.73.0/api/classes/BufferedProcess.html):

```
{BufferedProcess} = require 'atom'

 command = 'ps'
 args = ['-ef']
 stdout = (output) -> console.log(output)
 exit = (code) -> console.log("ps -ef exited with #{code}")
 process = new BufferredProcess({command, args, stdout, exit})
```

More fleshed out example (modified) from [atom-script](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/master/lib/script-view.coffee#L144-L159):

```
{BufferedProcess} = require 'atom'

command = "open"
args = ["/path/to/Transmit.app"]

# Default to where the user opened atom
options =
  cwd: atom.project.getPath()
  env: process.env

stdout = (output) -> console.log(output)
stderr = (output) -> console.error(output)

exit = (return_code) ->
  if return_code is 0
    console.log("Exited with 0")
  else
    console.log("Exited with " + return_code)

# Run process
bufferedProcess = new BufferedProcess({command, args, options, stdout, stderr, exit})
```

If you choose to go the spawn route, I recommend checking out how [test-status](https://github.com/tombell/test-status) does it.

Answer (score 1):

My quick google search said that Atom Editor has nodejs integrated, so you should be able to use [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

```
{spawn} = require 'child_process'
spawn 'path/to/your/transmit/app'
```